# I do not understand this sentence: "Resistor is used to stop loading the transistor"

Tags: transistors, resistors, load

[image: https://www.electronicshub.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/infrared-control-remote-switch-Receiver-Circuit-1024x425.jpg]

In this circuit, resistor R4 (just before the transistor) is used to stop loading the transistor.

I do not understand the part "resistor used to stop loading the transistor".

Comment: "to stop damaging the transistor" would be more accurate. Not to mention damaging the 4018 and the LED.

Comment: It is to limit current through the transistor.

Comment: It's weird, inaccurate wording.

Comment: it probably means ... `resistor used to prevent overloading the transistor`

Comment: It's not a good sentence. Is it translated from some other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, as other commenters have stated, "to limit the current through LED and the transistor". Here's the equivalent circuit of that section:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIi00j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

!Q1 output of U1 can be at the level of U1's supply voltage, 12V.

From KVL, \$\mathrm{12V = V_{D7} + V_{R4} + V_{BE-Q7}}\$

So, the current flowing through these components will be \$\mathrm{(12V-2\cdot(0.6V))/660\Omega = 16mA}\$ which is quite acceptable for illuminating an indicator LED and saturating a transistor which drives a relay.

If R4 is shorted then D7 and the BE junction of the transistor Q1 will see the full 12V across them. Here's what can happen next:

- The !Q1 output of U1 will see very low resistance. So a high current will flow through the diode and the transistor's BE junction even for a short time.
- BE junction of Q1 (and thus the transistor) and/or D7 will break down which (most likely) results in a short-circuit.
- Finally, the !Q1 output of U1 will see even lower resistance which may result in destroying the pin's output driver if there's no on-chip current limiting mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand clearly. Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: @Ayushprime you can accept my answer.

Comment: How to  accept as I am new to electrical stack